# Using mousedown HostListener to move elements around (Drag & Drop)

Tags: angular, angular-directive

We need to create a `drag and drop` directive. Using `drag and drop events` won't work for SVG elements, thus, we need to go for standard `mousedown`, `mousemove` and `mouseup` events. I saw a few examples in JavaScript, but somehow I don't get it working with Angular.

The `mousemove` works solong the draggable element is not selected.

How can I pick the element and drag it around with `HostListener` `mousemove`?

I created a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xu6qnt?file=app%2Fdraggable.directive.ts) so you can see what I've done. If I drag the element and open the console, you'll see that the `mousemove` event won't be fired.

what am I missing?

Comment: Do you want to drop the black block into the red block or reposition the black block?

Comment: I need both actualy. I should be able to drop, then inside the droppable area move it around.

Comment: Won't the html5 drag&drop api suffice for the first bit then?

Comment: yes, but this would not solve my problem. in the end I need to move SVG elements around and it won't work with HTML5 drag&drop events.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I supported an easy way to solve because of event stuck.

Apparently, out first goal is stop the event that is `preventdefault` .
In your `hostListener` , it supported in your `event`.

```
event.preventDefault();
```

In addition, it got more easy way is `return false` and it would be interrupt.

```
@HostListener('document:mousedown', ['$event'])
onMouseDown(event) {
  // we make sure only draggables on the document elements are selected
  if (event.target.getAttribute('draggable')) {
    console.log('mousedown');

    this.currentX = event.clientX;
    this.currentY = event.clientY;
    this.selectedElement = event.target;
    // ##### add this code.
    event.preventDefault();    // choose one
    // ##### or add this code.
    return false;    // choose one
  }
}
```

Comment: that is a reliable solution, the element is not following the mouse pointer tho. any idea why?

Comment: Check the mousedown and works your mouse move function

Comment: Normally, with lots of responses out there, its easy to tell when English isn't a first language, but that doesn't have to be a problem, since the idea can get across. Here though, this isn't the case. (Also, this solution did not help me!)